# Where can I find examples of nonfiction book proposals?

Tags: publishing, non-fiction

I am looking for complete examples of nonfiction book proposals. Preferably, these would be proposals that resulted in actual published works.

I've already read [Larsen's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/158297702X), and it does have some samples in it. I am also curious about the actual format in which these are generally submitted - MS Word, PDF, etc.

Comment: This question is asking for, essentially, a list of examples. Can you tell us what it is you need to find out by looking at examples? Maybe we can help answer your question rather than just provide links.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a bit on the internet and I have found this:

http://writersedgeservice.com/sample-book-proposal-from-a-professional-literary-agency/